# Using a text inside a math environment in a pgfplots label

Tags: math-mode, pgfplots

How is it possible to have a `\text{}` field inside of a math environment of a `pgfplots` label. A minimum not working example is displayed below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=$c^\text{ref}$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that `$c^\text{ref}$` is a valid latex syntax.

The error message thrown looks like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@label@ ->$c^\text 
                            {ref}$
l.26    \end{axis}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried adding `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: Or you could use \textrm or \texttt or \textsf.

Comment: @yo' Sorry that I have added an answer even after you commented. :). I am going for the `pgfplots` badge. Apologies. :)

Answer (score 4):

The error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplots@label@ ->$c^\text 
                            {ref}$
l.26    \end{axis}
```

indicates that the macro `\text` is not defined. This happens when you don't load `amsmath` package since the macro `\text` is defined by the package `amsmath`.

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   %% comment this line to get the error.
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=$c^{\text{ref}}$]
    \addplot coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `amsmath` loaded, the error goes away.

Comment: Also might not be a good idea to always relay on `^\text` working, but be better to use `^{\text{....}}`

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for your answer. Indeed this seems to be the problem. Strangely enough I had the same hunch but never tested it ^^. Since I am working with Lyx I thought that Lyx loads `amsmath` automatically anyways.